# Getting the right video format

Tags: 8.0, video

I have a Nokia Lumia 820 with an SD card and I'd like to get some videos on there for my little girl to watch.

I've already ripped a number of DVDs using [DVDFab](http://www.dvdfab.com/dvd-ripper.htm) and converting to a 'generic avi' format. The files play fine on Windows and my USB DVD player with no trouble but when I try to sync them to my phone there's a long wait while the desktop application says it is converting the videos and then I get a 'could not convert' (or something similar) message.

I've already ripped a bunch of them so I'd rather not do all that again and DVDFab should be able to convert from one format to the other.

So what video format (codec?) do movies need to be in order for them to successfully be converted by the sync software?

Comment: Given that the camera records video in MP4 format, I think that would work.

Comment: You have tagged this question as `windows-8` but did you mean `windows-phone-8`?

Comment: You can use [moliplayer](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/moliplayer-pro/19ea6d3e-e3d9-401d-b30a-f6471811fe08) app to play almost any format you want.
have fun.

Answer (score 1):

[AVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave) is a [container format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats), what matters is the codec that it is encoded with. I cannot tell you with the details you provided if what you have done will work, but Microsoft has listed an [extensive chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) as to what underlying codecs are supported.

Comment: Wow those charts are nearly incomprehensible! Will have to study up on them and find out which processor the 820 has

Comment: I know they're a bit much, but if you want to KNOW that what you have will work, its worth the research.

Comment: Those charts are tough to read because they are aimed at developers, not end users. To get you started, the processor built into the Lumia 820 is a Qualcomm Snapdragon S4 plus, more specifically the model MSM8960: http://www.knowyourmobile.com/nokia/nokia-lumia-920/18262/nokia-lumia-920-vs-nokia-lumia-820