# Supported video formats

Tags: 8.0, video

What are the type of video formats (*without the help of additional video players/apps*) supported by Windows Phone other than .3gp and .mp4?

Comment: Related: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2540/getting-the-right-video-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone [generally supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_VideoSupport): 3GP, 3G2, WMV, MP4, M4V, AVI, MOV files that use H.263, VC1, MPEG-4 Pt 2 or H.264 codecs.

Depending on individual phone model (and therefore processor), some phones will support differing maximum resolutions, etc.

Comment: But MPEG-4 is not working in Lumia 525 !pls clarify.

Comment: What resolution is the file in question?

Comment: its 720p and datarate is 192kbps.

Comment: 192kbps seems a very low bitrate for *720p video* - which makes me wonder which profile/other settings/were used making your file