# Video bitrate and other settings

Tags: video

I want to transfer some movies from my PC to my phone. I have a Nokia Lumia 635. What codecs and other settings are a good choice for this phone? I don't know which ones are compatible.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/supported-video-formats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the phone does not have an HD display you can reduce the size to 480p.

[These codes are supported](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/phone/lumia635/specifications/#head_video-and-audio): H.263, H.264/AVC, MPEG-4, VC-1, Windows-Video

I personally think Windows Live Movie Maker does a good job of converting videos for Windows Phone, but there are a lot of other great tools as well.

Comment: What are some good bitrates to use?

Comment: audio or video?

Comment: Both audio and video.